# are AsciiEffect.js && CSS3DRenderer.js compatible? three.js / WebGL

Tags: css, three.js, ascii, renderer

I'm trying to use the  [AsciiEffect.js](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_ascii_effect.html) && the [CSS3DRenderer.js](http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/) in combination, but don't know if that's possible without some finagling... here's the idea

```
var W = window.innerWidth, H = window.innerHeight;
renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
effect = new THREE.AsciiEffect( renderer );
effect.setSize( W, H );
document.body.appendChild( effect.domElement );
```

but that doesn't work... here's the problem, it's my understanding the AsciiEffect script uses the canvas renderer... I'm not entirely sure how the CSS3DRenderer works (beyond my skill set)... but in theory this seems like it should be possible... no? I assume it involves making some changes to either or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they're not. `AsciiEffect` only works with `canvas`-based renderers: `CanvasRenderer`, `SoftwareRenderer` and `WebGLRenderer`.